# Is it possible to create nested routes with multiple levels using react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a react app that has multiple levels, (landing pages, app pages and mobile pages)
my app routes look like this in the root component:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path = '/' component={LandingPages} />
  <Route path = '/app' component={AppPages} />
  <Route path = '/mobile' component={MobilePages} />
</Switch>
```

The '/' route goes to the LandingPages component which has routes like this:

```
        <Switch>
            <Route exact  path='/' component={HomePage} />
            <Route path = '//privacypolicy' component={PrivacyPolicy} />
            <Route path = '/termsandconditions' component={TermsnConditions} />
        </Switch>
```

The '/app route has:

```
       <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/app' component = {Dashboard} />
            <Route path='/app/signin' component={SignIn} />
            <Route path='/app/resetpassword' component={ResetPassword} />
            <Route path='/app/register' component={Register} />
        </Switch>
```

The 'mobile' route has:

```
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/mobile' component = {MobHome} />
        <Route exact path='/mobile/one' component = {One} />
    </Switch>
```

The home routes show blank when I make the '/' exact in the root component but work when I do it in the landing component. But then the other routes dont show if the '/' is not exact in the route.

How can I set them to all work at the same time.

I am new to react so pardon me if the question seems silly,

Comment: Nested routes will be rendered if parent route is not marked as `exact` but then (as you mentioned) routes below the `/` will not render because of `Switch` component (`Switch` will render only the first matching route). You can try changing the order of the `Route` components in the root component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When *actually* nesting your routes then no `Route` components with nested sub-routes can specify the `exact` prop because the nested routes won't be able to match *exactly* and be rendered.

Take a look at `react-router-dom`'s [nesting](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) example.

Another aspect to take note of, within `Switch` components, path order and specificity matter. The `Switch` will attempt to return and render ***the first match*** it finds, you will want to order the routes to list your *more* specific paths before *less* specific paths. In other words, `"/segment1/segment2"` *before* `"/segment1"` *before* `"/"`.

Root level

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/app' component={AppPages} />
  <Route path='/mobile' component={MobilePages} />
  <Route path='/' component={LandingPages} />
</Switch>
```

Use the `useRouteMatch` hook to access the current `path`.

> path - (string) The path pattern used to match. Useful for building
> nested `<Route>`s

Landing pages

```
const { path } = useRouteMatch();

...

<Switch>
  <Route path={`${path}/privacypolicy`} component={PrivacyPolicy} />
  <Route path={`${path}/termsandconditions`} component={TermsnConditions} />
  <Route path={path} component={HomePage} />
</Switch>
```

App pages

```
const { path } = useRouteMatch();

...

<Switch>
  <Route path={`${path}/signin`} component={SignIn} />
  <Route path={`${path}/resetpassword`} component={ResetPassword} />
  <Route path={`${path}/register`} component={Register} />
  <Route path={path} component={Dashboard} />
</Switch>
```

Mobile pages

```
const { path } = useRouteMatch();

...

<Switch>
  <Route path={`${path}/one`} component={One} />
  <Route path={path} component={MobHome} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thank you. let me try this.